# Distribution of number of distinct digits from 0 to 999

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, decimal-expansion

I used the online [Number Theory Terminal](http://ntt.beautyofmath.org/) of BoM to understand some more about the digit distribution of numbers. I used `dcount == d` to display all numbers with `d` distinct digits from 0 up to 999. I found out following sequence:

```
dcount == 0 , 0 numbers
dcount == 1 , 28 numbers
dcount == 2 , 324 numbers
dcount == 3 , 648 numbers
dcount >= 4 , 0 numbers
```

Because of this I was wondering (1) how to explain this sequence (e.g. 648 = 324*2 but how to get from 28 to 324) and (2) if there is a general expression $N(x,d)$ to calculate the amount of numbers $N$ to $x$ that have exacly $d$ distinct digits.

Comment: I see only 27 numbers with a digit count of 1: 1, 2, ..., 9, 11, 22, ..., 99, 111, 222, ...,999.

Comment: you are missing 0

Comment: So what exactly is the range you are considering? Please update the question.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the typo

Comment: You are not including 1000, either, apparently.

Comment: Side note: this seems a bit unnatural from a pure counting-and-combinatorics perspective because $0001$ is taken to be $1$.

Comment: Why does the title mention digit sums, but sums are nowhere mentioned in the question?

Comment: yes you are right, I was somewhat focused of what to write that I forgot to put a correct titel

Answer (score 0):

To have dcount=1, you need a single digit number, of which there are $10$, or a two or three digit number where have nine choices for the digit and two choices for the number of digits, for $18$ and a total of $28$.  For dcount=3 you have nine choices for the first digit as zero is not allowed, nine choices for the second since it can't match the first, and eight choices for the third since it can't match one of the first two.  $9 \cdot 9 \cdot 8=648$.  All the rest have dcount=2.  I don't think there is any magic in $324 \cdot 2=648$

Answer (score 0):

This may be of interest: just empirically, a graph of $N(x,d)$ for $1\le{x}\lt{100000}$.
[image]